# Dynamically assigning values in AJAX js calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I've recently started experimenting with react and I'm trying to push the boundaries (At least in my mind it seems like magic).

I'm trying to create a component that posts to a pre-defined API, using a dynamic data structure i.e. I want to pass the data param as a prop. Here is an example of my current AJAX code:

```
  createModalSubmit(form) {
    var name = this.refs.name.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: `/items.json`,
      type: 'POST',
      data: item:{name: name} ,
      success: (item) => {
        this.setState({
          item: {
            name: ''
          },
          errors: {},
          showModal: false
        });
      },
      error: (item) => {
        this.setState({errors: item.responseJSON.errors})
      }
    });
  },
```

How would I pass the data attribute as a prop in this section of code? I tried doing this as a function i.e:

```
  formData() {
    return {
      myData: {
        item: {
          name: name
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

And then passing in this to my data attribute as 'this.formData', but this does not seem to provide happiness.

I tried using vars as well, but the functional method above, made the most sense to me.

What is the best way of passing dynamic values to an ajax js call?

Comment: You'd probably want to make this an object: `data: item:{name: name}` into `data: { item:{name: name} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can pass a dynamic value to the ajax call in React: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/ZpRyKb

In the example, the parent component `App` is maintaining a state with an object including urls. The parent component is then providing individual urls to its children (`Time` and `Photo`) via props.

Here is a full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      urls: {
        time: 'http://date.jsontest.com',
        photos: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Time url={this.state.urls.time} />
        <Photo url={this.state.urls.photos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Time extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: this.props.url,
      success: (response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.time,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let content;

    if (this.state.data) { 
      content = (
        <div>
          <h1>Current Time</h1>
          <p>{this.state.data}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      content = <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Photo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: this.props.url,
      success: (response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: response,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let content;

    if (this.state.data) { 
      content = (
        <div>
          <h1>Photo</h1>
          <img src={this.state.data[0].url}/>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      content = <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Herm, is this what you are after?

Comment: Thanks @PiotrBerebecki this seems awesome. Thanks for your effort.Does the getUrl function retrieve the current url? That seems to break my implementation. I want to explicitly pass a url to each component.

Comment: Would you like to have a parent element storing a list of urls and then pass them to the individual children components so that they can make ajax calls using different urls?

Comment: Herm, I've just added an example. Would you like me to add anything or does it answer your question?

Comment: @Herm Please remember to mark this as an answer if you're happy with it. Good answer Piotr.